# Error in np.apply_along_axis in string clustering

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I am replicating the following example.
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37026/string-matching-and-clustering?newreg=cb75d7017b9e48d082161b53d5037891

```
from jellyfish import jaro_distance

words = 'CHEESE CHORES GEESE GLOVES'.split()

def d(coord):
    i, j = coord
    return (1 - jaro_distance(words[i], words[j]))

import numpy as np

a=np.triu_indices(len(words), 1)

np.apply_along_axis(d, axis=0, arr=a)
```

The last line np.apply_along_axis gives me the following error:

```
      1 def d(coord):
----> 2     i, j = coord
      3     return (1 - jaro_distance(words[i], words[j]))

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Cannot understand the reason. In the example, it seems to run.

Comment: What version of numpy are you running? Seems to work fine on 1.14.3, provided that for Python2.7 you also change your sample data to be unicode. Python3 won't need that last part.

Comment: I am using python 2.7 and numpy 1.14.3 only. What is exact problem in sample data?

Comment: The MVCE you posted is not the one that generated the error. Your trace shows that you ran  `np.apply_along_axis(d, axis=-1, arr=a)`, not with `axis=0`.

Comment: @OliverW. I was doing some hit and trial. In hurry posted the wrong trace. So the fix is as you said, in python 2.7 the input has to be in unicode. You can give the answer, so that I can accept it, if you intend to so. Thanks;)